# algorithm that calculates a minimum amount to be paid to pay off a balance in 12 months

Tags: python

I'm struggling with a problem that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a fixed monthly payment, I mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount, multiple of 10 and the same for all months, that will be paid each month. ( it is possible for the balance to become negative using this payment scheme, which is OK)

So as input I have

```
original_balance = 3329

annualInterestRate = 0.2
```

From this I'm calculating the followings :

```
after_12_months_interest = original_balance
monthlyInterestRate = round(annualInterestRate/12.0,2)
monthly_payment = 10
total_paid = 0

for i in range(0,12):
    after_12_months_interest = after_12_months_interest + (annualInterestRate/12.0)*after_12_months_interest

while total_paid < after_12_months_interest:
    new_balance = 0
    unpaid_balance = original_balance - monthly_payment 
    total_paid = 0
    for i in range(0, 13):
        total_paid = total_paid + monthly_payment
    if total_paid < after_12_months_interest:
        monthly_payment = monthly_payment + 10

print "Lowest Payment: ", monthly_payment
```

My problem I have is that I end up having a monthly_payment just a little more than I should have it. In this case the return for the monthly_payment is 320 instead of 310. For all use cases I've tried the monthly_payment it's slightly more than it should be.

Anyone can give me a hint or an idea on what I'm doing wrong please. Thank you

Comment: your interests are computed monthly, based on what you *still* owe. meaning your `after_12_months_interest` is not valid, as it computes the interests on the whole sum.

Comment: There is a well known formula for calculating a payment based on starting balance, interest rate, and number of payments. Find that formula and the code becomes a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

## Mandatory one-liner

```
from itertools import count

print(next(payment for payment in count(0, 10) 
    if sum(payment*(1+monthly)**i for i in range(12)) > original_balance*(1+annual)))
```

What this does:

- `next` takes the first element of an iterator.
- `count` tries values from 0 to infinity (only each time `next` is called, and only until a value is returned)
- `sum(payment*(1+monthly)**i for i in range(12))` That's the combined value of the payments. Each payment is worth itself plus all the saved interests (the earlier you repay, the less interest you'll owe later)
- `original_balance*(1+annual)` is indeed the total value if nothing is repayed.

## Alternative

```
print(next(payment for payment in count(0, 10) 
    if reduce(lambda x,_:(x - payment)*(1+monthly), range(12), original_balance) <= 0))
```

This one computes the combined remainder of the debt by `reduce`ing the original_balance 12 times.